# what shoud be difference between "NativeHeapAllocatedSize" and "Runtime totalMemory" in Android to prevent from "OutOfmemory Exception"?

Tags: android

hello i m doing some runtime calculation for getting NativeHeap memory and allocated memory at runtime, so any one can suggest me

what should be the difference between "Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()" and "Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()"

so can prevent app by OutOf Memory Exception.

Thanks

Comment: I think it 5 MB ...as I experienced it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

Returns the total amount of memory which is available to the running program.

```
getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()
```

For devices below HoneyComb most of the huge allocations are deferred to the native heap (e.g Bitmaps). Hence this api is useful to find out how much of native heap is allocated.

OOM Errors occurs when there are no objects which can be freed by the DVM. Typically you have about 16MB in the Heap to play with (for a standard phone). Check [your logs*](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/memory_management_for_android_apps.pdf) to see GC statements having info about how much of memory is allocated.

I don't think there should be a fixed ratio to cause an OOM error. Like in the case when you load a very huge bitmap, here the native memory used is huge.

- Slide 25

Comment: what can be max size of Native Heap?

Comment: That is again, relative to the amount of memory available to every phone.

Comment: means like if in my phone i have 1GB RAM, then Native Heap will be 1 GB, is it the case?

Comment: No about 48 Mb, there are other internal processes etc which need that memory

Comment: thanks , but can u pls explain me more specific, how it be around 48 MB and where other part of Native memory used.

Comment: Basically it's more of a Java thing. Java sets limits like that to keep applications from eating up all of the RAM.